# popup window blocked in ajax success handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am trying to open a popup window to allow a user to authenticate with twitter without having to leave the page they are viewing. I have seen this technique used around the web, particularly with the Disqus commenting application. However, I am only able to get two results, either a 'Popup window blocked' message or nothing even happens.

I have tried using the approaches outlined [here](http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html) and [here](http://www.codebelt.com/jquery/open-new-browser-window-with-jquery-custom-size/). How can I fix this?

My code currently looks like:

```
var windowSizeArray = [ "width=200,height=200",
                            "width=300,height=400,scrollbars=yes" ];
var url = $('.twitter_popup').attr("href");
var windowName = $('.twitter_popup').attr("name");
var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$('.twitter_popup').attr("rel")];
window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
```

Comment: The popup-security model is about allowing only popups that are triggered by a user event, e.g. a click event. Can you share more context to verify that you're doing that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The popup blockers on the browser block the the popups when the code is executing in the script execution context.

E.g If we open a new window on an anchor click the popup blocker will not block it but if we try to open a new window using setTimeout you will see that popup blocker will block this. It is because when timeout is reached the context is now **script execution context** instead of user action. This is the same behavior when we try to open a new window in an ajax callback handler.

I think you are into similar such situation.

Live **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/CK6wm/3/)**

If for some reason you want to open the popup in ajax success handler itself then you can achieve it by making a synchronous ajax call. The popup will not be blocked.

Comment: This was the problem. I was opening the window in the 'success' action of a ajax call. I fixed it by opening the window, and executing the ajax from within the window instead. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The pop up was not blocked in latest chrome or firefox using setTimeout

Comment: @Orbit - Can you prove me with a `live` example? The example which I have is blocking popups in Chrome. Make yourself clear before down voting to any answer.

Comment: if i set the timeout higher , it fails

Comment: In your example I see Chrome is blocking the popup.

Comment: I'm sorry, try again. I was messing with the timeout value. I tried to remove the downvote, please edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might lie in the following areas...
1. the windowSizeArray contains only a single element.
2. the code $('.twitter_popup').attr("rel") might give you some diff results than expectd because class name is used as a selector

Comment: The windowSizeArray actually contains 2 elements, look closely.