# jQuery - ("a.class") load and window.open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http

Just a heads up, I understand why there would be rules against allowing this to function as it would be assumed to, due to the ramifications of someone opening a ton of spam pop-up windows, however, I'm wondering if it is at all possible to make it work.

Here's my code;

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    ("a.explode").load( 
    function() { var url = $(this).attr("href"); 
    window.open(url); }
    );                      
});
```

and

```
<a class="explode" href="http://www.google.com">Link1</a>
<a class="explode" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Link2</a>
<a class="explode" href="http://www.tumblr.com">Link3</a>
```

For those who don't understand what I'm trying to do, on page load, several windows are opened, using the `href=""` attribute of `<a class="explode">`.

**POST EXPERIMENTATION EDIT:** After working through this with a lovely member of SO, we figured out that this is not worth implementing/impossible (due to pop-up blockers most browsers natively have). `window.open()` must be bound to a `.click()` event, in effect making the concept useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `$` in the code while selecting anchors. Use `each` block and `href` property of anchor like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.explode").each(function() {  
      window.open(this.href); 
    });
});
```

Comment: @Pixelatron - Did you try this?

Comment: Tried, still doesn't work unfortunately. Here's my jsFiddle (although even if it did work, it probably wouldn't allow `window.open()` or something?) http://jsfiddle.net/j8y7S/

Comment: See, if the popups are blocked the you cannot open a new window. You can only open a new window through users actions. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059902/popup-window-blocked-in-ajax-success-handler/7060302#7060302

Comment: is `.hover()` considered a user action? Could I pull a blanket `.hover()` on the `<body>` tag to call it?

Comment: Yes you can do it in hover event.

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle, however it seems to be broken. To test, I added in the jQuery function `addClass()` yet it still doesn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/j8y7S/1/ :(. Thanks for your help so far anywhere, it means a lot :).

Comment: @ShankarSangoli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2474/discussion-between-pixelatron-and-shankarsangoli)

Comment: @Pixelatron - In your fiddle you had again missed to add `$` while selecting the anchors. But I tried it with hover its not working. We have to use `click` event. Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j8y7S/7/

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up :). I'll take that function off my list then ;). Really though, thanks so much for all your input. I'll accept this answer + edit my question, so that others know that it can't be done without being binded to a `.click()` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just go through all anchor elements with *each*? And yes, I think it would be kind of anoying if a page starts opening popups out of nowhere...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    ("a.explode").each( 
    function() { var url = $(this).attr("href"); 
    window.open(url); }
    );                      
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, apparently `window.open()` can only be called by user events, as oppose to on load? Here's my jsFiddle though, perhaps you could debug it if you know otherwise :) http://jsfiddle.net/j8y7S/. Thanks for your feedback, it really means a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.explode").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(url);        
});
```

Not sure what you are trying to do though, .load() is an ajax function used to load content from an internal domain within a specified element. So by  `("a.explode").load(...` you are trying to load those sites within the a tags as anchor text? Also if, all you are trying to do is open these sites in a new window when the user clicks on the links then why not just use target="_blank" as a previous member suggested.

Comment: I was more trying to have all sites open at once in different windows, which at the moment doesn't seem to be possible :(.