# FB.login() invoke popup window is blocked by Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, popup, settimeout

Extremely relevant:

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=256

Specifically:

> I've discovered that popups are blocked unless triggered by a user
>   action, e.g. a button click. So the solution to this problem is to
>   only call Facebook.login() from a MouseEvent.CLICK handler.

---

However on my website, this is what I do and the popup is *still* blocked:

```
$('#fb-login-button').click(function () {
    FB.logout();
    setTimeout(function() {
        FB.login();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Is it because the `FB.login()` call is being invoked by the setTimeout() function and not directly in the click handler?

Any suggestions?

Comment: how you will run above written code, FB.logout(), FB.login() functions will work on in its facebook jS SDK, then inside the SDK how you call these functions on a click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, browser blocks your popup because of setTimeout call.

if you remove setTimeout it won't be blocked.

great explanation is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7060302/384442